# Separate <tbody> with box-shadow

Tags: html, css, css-tables

How to separate **tbody** with **box-shadow** from another **tbody**?

Like a

```
tbody {
    margin-bottom: 16px
}
```

But, I don't want to use **display: block** on **tbody**.

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/kw9odqjr/1/

IMG what I want:
[image]

Comment: Could you add an image of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: ok! done, please check img

Comment: why you use `tbody` many time any reason?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of repeating `tbody` many time you can used below structure:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: none;
}

tbody table {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Jill</td>
              <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td>Jackson</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" height="20"></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" height="20"></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" height="20"></td></tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed to assign `margin` for `tbody`,
you can insert a separator like this

```
<tbody style="box-shadow:none; height:20px;">
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```